# "Browser or app may not be secure. Try using a different browser." error with Flutter Firebase Google Login

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web

I am using flutter web and firebase authentication to build a web app. For that
1. Created Firebase app with Google signin as one of the sign in methods.
2. Added the dependencies as given in https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example
and https://dart-pub.mirrors.sjtug.sjtu.edu.cn/packages/firebase_auth_web.

When I try to login, the Google sign-in window appears. Once I enter the email address and press enter, it gives the following error.

> "Couldn't sign you in This browser or app may not be secure. Try using
>   a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you
>   can refresh your screen and try again to sign in."

I used Chrome browser.
What should I do to make my app more secure ? For android, we had the option of using SHA keys to encrypt the connection. Do we need to do something similar for web ?

Comment: I'm facing the same error, possibly because when debugging we are not going over https? I don't know yet.

Comment: @MobileMon , The issue was with the chrome developer version Flutter use to launch as a device. If we open the same URL (localhost:portnumber) in the normal chrome, it will work without any issue.

Comment: I'm sure why, but yes!  I made a new google account and it worked.  Didn't even have to turn on "Less secure app access".  It just worked right away!  Not having 2-factor authentication enabled on the account might be part of it but not sure.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue was with the chrome developer version Flutter use to launch as a device. If we open the same URL (localhost:portnumber) in the normal chrome, it will work without any issue.

Comment: Do we need to run it only it release mode to for the same URL to work in different Chrome instance, or debug mode should be fine here?

Comment: @vzurd I tried launching the app with run -d chrome `--web-hostname localhost --web-port 5000` and then open a normal chrome page on host:5000 but it still fails. Have misinterpreted you answer? Is there a way to run it in non debug mode directly instead?

Comment: So what I did was in VS Code, run Start Debugging. It opens a new chrome debugging instance (new window) at localhost:5000. Then, open a regular chrome tab or window, different from the one that Flutter opened up. Type in localhost:5000, and you'll now be able to sign in.

Comment: when i do this i no longer see the system out of flutter which i need for seeing exception traxes etc

Comment: @vzurd, are you able to debug like that?

Answer (score 34):

#### Incomplete answer:

This problem isn't specific to flutter. It happens whenever you try to sign in to Google in a Chrome instance that has debugging turned on. In other words, if you, your automation software, or IDE starts up chrome with a command like `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`

If running Chrome normally (out of debug mode) is not an option, then try https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505?msgid=24501976 or if you are using Electron then try https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505?msgid=24503570 but I, personally, haven't been able to make these work for me, yet.

Please upvote the question at https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/25209002 if you want a solution to this problem that actually works.

Comment: Removing the --remote-debugging-port fixed the problem for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My chrome shortcut had this line after the exe  --process-per-site

Comment: I'm sure why, but yes!  I made a new google account and it worked.  Didn't even have to turn on "Less secure app access".  It just worked right away!  Not having 2-factor authentication enabled on the account might be part of it but not sure.

Comment: @MeetingAttender How did you remove the `--remote-debugging-port` ? Were you not running this via selenium automation?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

Go into your google account

1. select Manage Account
2. Security
3. Less secure app access (need to scroll down a little bit)
4. set to off

Then I was able to login in and debug in IntelliJ

*(for me, for some reason, I had to create a new google account, couldn't get it working with my existing account but it worked with my new account)*

Comment: I'm sure why, but yes!  I made a new google account and it worked.  Didn't even have to turn on "Less secure app access".  It just worked right away!  Not having 2-factor authentication enabled on the account might be part of it but not sure.

Comment: I believe the less secure apps option for allowing 3rd partiy Google account access is deprecated as of May 2022.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user agent switch to switch another browser (for example opera).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg

They try login. Once you successfully logged in you can remove or disable the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firefox. The only way I could fix it was to create a new profile. So you could try to run Firefox with -p switch and create a new profile.

```
 firefox -ProfileManager
 firefox.exe -p
```

Update: check the firefox config (address field: about:config)
be sure marionette.enabled is false

Answer (score 0):

For Test Automation Users-:I saw many testers are facing this issue for sign in using Google but I think below my idea will save their time.

Best Work Around is as below-:

1. Open automated Chrome browser as shown below

[image: Automated Chrome Browser Screenshot]

2. Sign up with new details which you want to use.
3. Now after successfully completion of sign up.
4. Then use that email and password for signing into gmail using Selenium or any other test automation tool