# puppeteer not able to log into google account

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

In puppeteer when opening regular chrome and trying to access a GMAIL account, get message:

> Couldn't sign you in This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
>   Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported
>   browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

Code:

```
var p = require("puppeteer");
var a = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36"
 p.launch({
    headless:false,
    args: [

    ],
    executablePath:"/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
}).then((b) => {
    console.log("ASD");
    b.newPage().then((g) => {
        g.evaluate(() => {

            var v = document.querySelector(".signUpLink")
            console.log("hi", v)


        })
        g.setUserAgent(a);
        Promise.all([
            g.goto("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=grandcentral&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fvoice.google.com%2Fsignup&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fvoice.google.com%2Fsignup&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"),
            g.setUserAgent(a),
            g.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
            g.waitForSelector(".signUpLink", {
                visible:true
            }),
            g.waitFor(3000),
            new Promise((r,e) => {
                console.log("hi")
                r();

            }),
            g.click(".signUpLink"),
            g.evaluate(() => {

                var v = document.querySelector(".signUpLink")
                console.log("hi", v)


            })
        ])
    })
})
```

fixes?

Comment: If that error message is because of something in the Chromium instance embedded in puppeteer, you can try configuring puppeteer to use actual Chrome instead of the embedded Chromium (you have to specify a path to your Chrome executable).

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, although I tried it with the default chrome app from the mac, but it still gives the error

Comment: See some description of issues here: https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505?hl=en and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480956/browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-try-using-a-different-browser-error-with-fl.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, I found thsoe links earlier although was not able to solve the problem from them. Same issue with foxr https://github.com/mozilla/node-firefox tried setting user agent, not sure any workaround

Comment: @bluejayke were you ever able to find a fix for this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @justanotherguy no I did it a while ago, but more recently I think the google sites somehow were able to detect that it was being logged in from developer mode, although I don't know how they could detect that...

Answer (score 5):

Google login doesn't allow automated login.
It was just recently they came up with this approach

Comment: Oh brutal do you know of any possible workarounds? Perhaps a custom browser? How can the Google website detect that the browser itself is being controlled from something else?

Comment: You can use dolphin-anty to solve this problem. But it won't be that straight forward like loading other browsers

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it to work with the below code.

`await page.setBypassCSP(true)` does the magic.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
// const chromium = require('@sparticuz/chrome-aws-lambda');
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')();
console.log(pluginStealth.availableEvasions); // => Set { 'user-agent', 'console.debug' }
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth);
pluginStealth.setMaxListeners = () => {};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    dumpio: process.env.STAGE === 'dev',
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
    headless: chromium.headless,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setBypassCSP(true)
```

Comment: are the other plugins needed?

Comment: also have u tested it with the specific login coed mentionde in the question?