# I am using selenium(python) to open youtube. But when it opens chrome, I am not signed in

Tags: python, selenium

When selenium opens youtube, I am not signed in and when I try to sign in, it says the following:

"This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in."

Is there any way to sign in

This is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Pranav Sandeep\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get('https://www.youtube.com')

SearchBar = browser.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("Selenium", Keys.ENTER)

Video = browser.find_element_by_id("video-title")
Video.click()
```

Comment: That's by design. Selenium launches browsers using a different profile.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Looks like this is due to remote debugging issue? Are you on Chrome 79? Refer to this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673634/1728790

Answer (score 0):

You need to first sign in to google and then you can go to youtube. Use this code below.

Use [Seleniumwire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) with [undetected browser v2](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#bot-detection)

> Note: put chromedriver in your sys path.

```
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import time

options = {}
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)

browser.get('https://gmail.com')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys('your-email')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys('you-password')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com')
```

In addition to this, selenium wire has many awesome features, check out Github [repository](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire)