# direct google 'sign in' on flutter webview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In part of my app i am trying to open google `sign in` in web view. I am using this web view configuration:

```
 body: SafeArea(
    child: WebView(
      userAgent: "Chrome/81.0.0.0 Mobile",
      initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
      initialUrl: url.toString(),
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onPageFinished: (val) {
        print('The result is $val');
      },
    ),
  ),
```

But after insert **email address** and touch `Next` button,I got this page in webView :
https://accounts.google.com/signin/rejected?rrk=46&hl=en

i got error as you can see in above link and below image:

[image]

Is there any solution ? With **url launcher** there is no problem but in web view i have a problem,

This is output of doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 1.17.0 at /mnt/Software/Linux/Flutter/flutter
• Framework revision e6b34c2 (9 days ago), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
• Engine revision 540786dd51
• Dart version 2.8.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at /mnt/Software/Linux/Android/SDK/
• Platform android-R, build-tools 29.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = /mnt/Software/Linux/Android/SDK
• Java binary at: /mnt/Software/Linux/Android/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
• Android Studio at /mnt/Software/Linux/Android/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
• Dart plugin version 192.7761
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
• VS Code at /usr/share/code
• Flutter extension version 3.10.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• LG K520 • LGK520355503e • android-arm • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673634/9142279 may help

Comment: I read this post but didn't understand much.I don't want to open with browser I want to open with webview@LoVe

Comment: Yeah I know this is not same as your case but it is the same problem I think, something to do with debug mode