# javafx Webview not working with google login

Tags: javafx, webview, google-signin, webengine

It seems Google has revoked the option of logging with "simple browsers" like javafx webview:
The URL:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>

works absolutely perfect in a "normal "browser like Edge/Chrome etc, but with webView, it displays a message saying :

GOOGLE screen after entering the google account

[Could not sign you in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJGG6.png)

Any ideas how to solve..?

Comment: I already tried a couple User Agent setting like:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
and a few others from: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/

I also tried setting the:
System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");
And enabling javascript:
webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

But still no success

Comment: Could it have something to do with the browser being in debug mode? As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59673634/2234009

Comment: @OgierSchelvis Not sure if that applies to webview/webengine?

Comment: Well it depends how you are using it, are you in the midst of developing something, it could mean that when you are tesing it in your development environment, it is operating in debug mode by default.

Comment: So it seems that it is not only webview that is struggling here. Even Google's own embedded browser Chromium has the same issue: 
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/embedder-dev/c/STyM5ZNTHMM/m/POj1v_cqBgAJ